# Why is the Camera Background image appearing greyish in Blender Viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, color, color-management

[image: Background Image Comparison in Different Section]

My background image appears greyish in the viewport. Why and how do I fix that?

[image]

1. The Image is just a simple *sRGB* png image with no transparency.
2. When I add it to the camera background, it appears a bit different from the original image. The black section of the image appears greyish in *3d Viewport* only.
3. Even though the *View Transform* mode under *Color Management* section doesn't affect background image, it is still set to *Standard*, not *Filmic*.
4. I have tried almost every possible thing to fix it and researched on every single blender forum in the universe but haven't found anything.

There's no problem in renders though while using *Compositor* and *Alpha Over* node. This problem is only visible in *3D viewport*

[image: Zoomed in comparison]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Is this a Camera Background Image?  If so, select the camera, go to the Camera Properties tab of the Properties Editor and open the Background Images pane.  Is Opacity set to 1?

Comment: I have attached the the blend file @YousufChaudhry

Comment: Opacity is set to 1. Please check attached blend file @MartyFouts

Comment: In the Render panel > Color Management > switch from Filmic to Standard

Comment: The image on the right side of your blend file is not all black. (It's on the left on your screenshot above.) If you switch to the image editor and use the eye dropper tool. On my LG monitor, as far as I can tell without getting out color measurement tools, the version displayed on the right (left in screenshot) looks the same, nearly black in the lower left corner, dark blue in the upper right, for instance.

Comment: Color Management tools doesn't affect background images. It stay same. @moonboots

Comment: Yes they are both nearly black, but not same. Even though the difference is tiny still it catches my eye every time I use Gradient background images and it looks bad while previewing darker objects in front of it  @MartyFouts

Comment: @Rakesh Dey it changes the colors in the UV Editor but it may be not what you're talking about

Comment: I suspect that the Background Image doesn't use OCIO display color management config but instead hard coded to display sRGB. Funny thing is the Movie Clip Background Images work correctly though.